# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function-Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Necesito ayuda con DataTables soy  nuevo y no se como usar correctamente el plugin, seguí el manual de la pagina oficial pero no logre hacer que funciones, a continuación adjunto una imagen y mis cogido php y js, espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.
pdt: quite muchas lineas de codigo por politas de la pagina, todo funciona solo es la parte de DataTables
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Adjunto la imagen y el código
Este còdigo es del peridos_lectivos.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<!-- DataTables --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datatables/datatables.min.css"/>
<!--datables estilo bootstrap 4 CSS-->  
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="datatables/DataTables- 
1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="main-wrapper" data-layout="vertical" data-navbarbg="skin5" data-sidebartype="full"
    data-sidebar-position="absolute" data-header-position="absolute" data-boxed-layout="full">
    <?php include "panel.php"; ?> 
    <div class="page-wrapper">
       
        <div class="page-breadcrumb bg-white">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h4 class="page-title">Registrar Periodos Lectivos
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data- 
     bs-target="#reg_periodos">Agregar <i class="fas fa-plus-square ms-2"></i> </button>
                    </h4>                     
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
       
        <div class="container-fluid">
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="white-box">
                    
                    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Office</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                    <th>Start date</th>
                                    <th>Salary</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                    <td>System Architect</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                </tr>
                              
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                    <td>London</td>
                                    <td>38</td>
                                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                                    <td>$163,500</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                                    <td>37</td>
                                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                                    <td>$139,575</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                                    <td>Developer</td>
                                    <td>New York</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                                    <td>$98,540</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                                    <td>47</td>
                                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                                    <td>$87,500</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                                    <td>Singapore</td>
                                    <td>64</td>
                                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                                    <td>$138,575</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                    <td>New York</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                                    <td>$125,250</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                                    <td>56</td>
                                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                                    <td>$115,000</td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                                    <td>Singapore</td>
                                    <td>29</td>
                                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                                    <td>$183,000</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                                    <td>New York</td>
                                    <td>27</td>
                                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                                    <td>$112,000</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Office</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                    <th>Start date</th>
                                    <th>Salary</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer text-center"> 2021 © Ample Admin brought to you by <a
                href="https://www.wrappixel.com/">wrappixel.com</a>
        </footer      
      </div>     
   </div>
  <!-- JQuery-->
  <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>    
  <!-- para usar botones en datatables JS -->
  <script src="datatables/Buttons-1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="datatables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>   
  <script src="datatables/Buttons-1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app-style-switcher.js"></script>
 <!--Wave Effects -->
 <script src="js/waves.js"></script>
 <!--Menu sidebar -->
 <script src="js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
 <!--Custom JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
 <!-- Functions JS -->
 <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

 <!-- SweetAlert 2 -->
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</body>
```

Aquí adjunto el functions.js que es el archivo donde llamo a la funcion de Datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
} );
} );
```

Comment: Quiero utilizar el modelo que cuenta con botones de Excel, PDF , etc ; link del ejemplo https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: Saludos. De primera impresión te puedo sugerir que revise las rutas; son relativas a tu html y no (parece *absolutas* al sitio) por tanto revisa que de tu html (bueno tu php) .

Comment: al final todo estaba bien , y vi un video donde agg defer al lado del srcipt del datatable y funciono todo, fue muy raro la vdd